# Stop AvPlayer and listen to an other url

Tags: xcode, avplayer

I've tried this, but if I start a new URL, both URL are going to play at the same time.

In PlayerViewController.h

```
AVPlayer                         *radioPlayer;
```

In PlayerViewController.m

```
- (void)Play_pressed{
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://listen.radionomy.com/radiomyme-tv"];
radioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
[radioPlayer play];}

- (void)Stop_pressed{
[radioPlayer pause];
[radioPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:nil];
[radioPlayer pause];
radioPlayer = nil;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved ! You just need to add one line in Stop_pressed

```
- (void)Stop_pressed{
[radioPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:(nil)];
}
```